# Devolping Eclipse Plugin. Create Subcategory in plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This is my plugin.xml

```xml
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards"> 
      <category 
        id="root" 
        name="Root Category"> 
      </category> 
      <category 
        id="first_subcategory" 
        name="Sub Category"
        parentCategory="root"> 
      </category>       
      <wizard 
          id="first_leaf_of_subcategory" 
          name="Wizard of First Subcategory" 
          category="root/first_subcategory" 
          icon="./icons/sample.gif" 
          class="com.myplugin.WizFirstSubCategory"
          project="true"
          > 
          <description> 
              Create a simple wizard of First Subcategory
          </description>         
      </wizard> 
   </extension> 
</plugin>
```

Whe I run My plugin as Eclipse Application I don't find the three that I wrote.
I want "New-->Project" open wizard that have inside "Root Category-->Sub Category-->Wizard of First Subcategory" but doesn't work

If I delete Subcategory and reference first_leaf_of_subcategory directly at root plugin works if i insert a subcategory doesn't works.

I read documentation [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_navigator_navigatorContent.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally this tree works for me.

```
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards"> 
      <!-- ROOT CATEGORY -->
      <category 
        id="root_category" 
        name="Root Category"> 
      </category>
      <!-- FIRST SUB CATEGORY -->   
      <category 
        id="first_sub_category"
        name="First Sub Category"
        parentCategory="root_category"> 
      </category>       
      <wizard 
          id="firstWizS1" 
          name="First Wiz S1" 
          category="root_category/first_sub_category" 
          icon="./icons/firstWizS1.png" 
          class="com.mycategory.FirstWizS1"
          project="true">      
      </wizard> 
      <wizard 
          id="secondWizS1" 
          name="Second Wiz S1" 
          category="root_category/first_sub_category" 
          icon="./icons/secondWizS1.png" 
          class="com.mycategory.SecondWizS1"
          project="true">      
      </wizard>
      <!-- SECOND SUB CATEGORY --> 
      <category 
        id="second_sub_category"
        name="Second Sub Category"
        parentCategory="root_category"> 
      </category>
      <wizard 
          id="firstWizS2" 
          name="First Wiz S2" 
          category="root_category/second_sub_category" 
          icon="./icons/firstWizS2.png" 
          class="com.mycategory.FirstWizS2"
          project="true">      
      </wizard> 
      <wizard 
          id="secondWizS1" 
          name="Second Wiz S1" 
          category="root_category/second_sub_category" 
          icon="./icons/secondWizS2.png" 
          class="com.mycategory.SecondWizS2"
          project="true">      
      </wizard>
   </extension>    
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for the last few min. Thank you very much! Great help.